# Am I doing the correct data transformation for Granger causality tests

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, autocorrelation, stationarity, granger-causality

I have seven sets of time series, below is my process flow, am I doing the correct thing here? especially step 4.

1. Raw data
2. transform and test stationary with unit root test (ADF), with level, first difference, second difference, logarithm, first difference of logarithm, if p<0.05, the transformed dataset is stationary(table2)
3. transform and test autocorrelation with Durbin-Watson stat, with level, first difference, second difference, logarithm, first difference of logarithm, choose the one with a DW value closest to 2(table3)

[image]

**4. select the transformed datasets with the lowest P value and the DW value closest to 2 (red marked variables).**

5. Run granger causality test with the selected tranformed datasets (red marked variables). If p<0.05, reject null hypotheses